# Can not design backtracking pseudo code for the following scenario

Tags: algorithm, backtracking

I am fighting with the following problem and the more I think the more I confused:

let's say we have S which is a set of triple S is a set {(x,y,z) | x,y,z is in X} and X is a set of numbers. Now I want to write a backtracking pseudocode that return true if there is a subset S' of S such that every element of X occurs in exactly one triple of A?

I tried to remove element q from X and check if the any triple in S' contains X, if not I used the for loop in S to find triple contains q and push that triple to S' but exactly at this point I know I am wrong because then the added triple in S' may affect other elements added before in S'.

I am totally stuck and I do not know where to start.

I appreciate if anyone can help?

Comment: One way to do it is to enumerate all subsets of S' using backtracking and keep track of all the "visited" items from X. That way you get an expected runtime of *O(2^|S|)* (or deterministic if the numbers in X are bounded and you can just use a lookup table instead of a  hash table)

Comment: Thanks a lot.Do you think it is better that I use recursion  . I am still confused how can I enumerate s' with backtracking(it is noteworthy that S' starts with empty because at first I have nothing in it)? Can you please explain it more?

Comment: Yes, recursion is a good idea. That way you can build the visited set incrementally, leading to an *O(2^|S|)* runtime. The straightforward way of enumerating each subset and for each one check if there is an overlap would be *O(|S| * 2^|S|)*, so slightly less efficient. The backtracking itself works in a way that for every member of S, you have two options: Either take it or not take it into the subset. So you just try both and recurse